# Android Studio: unable to find valid certification path to requested target using Proxy

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

I am under enterprise network and I have tried adding proxies into android studio as well as in gradle but still I am facing this issue of certificate path.

I have also tried adding jcenter cert to studio but it does not help either.

Here are the logs:

```
 Caused by: 
 org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not 
 GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/a
 ndroid/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)

... 151 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
```

Answer (score 2):

An enterprise firewall is unlikely to cause a certificate issue.

Java uses its own certificate bundle and you may have an older JDK that doesn't have the root certificate for dl.google.com.

Check what JDK your Studio is running on and if needed, get a more recent one. Android Studio comes with its own JDK, if you're using that you can switch to a different newer one: if I recall correctly, the setting is in "File" -> "Project Stucture" -> "Sdk Location"; or you can upgrade Studio itself.

Comment: Hi @Leo, I was using the embedded JDK. I tried changing it to other java-8 version but the issue is same.

Comment: What OS are you running this on and what is the Studio version? You may want to try setting `STUDIO_JDK=/path/to/new/jdk` in the environment when starting it. Also, to exclude any chance there is an issue with the proxy/firewall: try downloading manually the file that Gradle is trying to get (with `wget` or `curl` or whatever other utility you have for downloading from the Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Im my case the problem was solved installing the jdk8